# Conditionally replace values on three 2d numpy arrays

Tags: numpy

I have three 2x2 numpy arrays like so:

```
import numpy as np

#create three arrays
one = np.array([[1, -1], 
                [-1, 1]])

two = np.array([[-1, 0], 
                [-2, 2]])

three = np.array([[1, 1], 
                [-4, 3]])
```

I want to make a fourth 2x2 array and replace the values based on `one`, `two` and `three` so that if in a particular location all three arrays have values less than one, to make the new value -1, and if all three arrays have values greater than one, to make the new value 1.  If the condition is not met I want to turn the values to 0.

I am attempting this like so:

```
#make a copy of one 
final = one.copy()

#where all of the three initial arrays are > 0 make the value 1
final[(one > 0) & (two > 0) & (three >0)] = 1

#where all of the three initial arrays are < 0 make the value -1
final[(one < 0) & (two < 0) & (three <0)] = -1
```

which returns:

```
array([[ 1, -1],
       [-1,  1]])
```

So in this case the index at `[0,0]` and `[0,1]` I want to return zero while `[1,0]` should be -1 and `[1,1]` should be 1 or this:

```
[0, 0,
[-1, 1]
```

I think it is because I am not saying how to change the value to 0 when the original two conditions are not met, and I can't seem to work out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for multiple choices on conditions (and default value `0`):

```
final = np.select([(one > 0) & (two > 0) & (three > 0), 
                   (one < 0) & (two < 0) & (three < 0)], [1, -1])
print(final)
```

---

```
[[ 0  0]
 [-1  1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your initialization is incorrect, you should set up zeros not the values of "one":

```
final = np.zeros_like(one)

final[(one > 0) & (two > 0) & (three >0)] = 1
final[(one < 0) & (two < 0) & (three <0)] = -1
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0,  0],
       [-1,  1]])
```

An alternative similar to that of Roman, but using `dstack` and `all` to generalize the comparisons to an arbitrary number of input arrays:

```
a = np.dstack([one, two, three])
final = np.select([(a>0).all(-1), (a<0).all(-1)], [1, -1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
n = 3
a = np.stack([one, two, three])
b = np.sign(a).sum(axis=0)
(b == n) - 1*(b == -n)
```

---

Alternatively:

```
a = np.stack([one, two, three])
np.where(np.all(a > 0, axis=0), 1, np.where(np.all(a < 0, axis=0), -1, 0))
```

---

Output:

```
array([[ 0,  0],
       [-1,  1]])
```